# Как отследить любое обращение к JCR ноде?

Tags: java, aem, cq5, jcr

Начинаю работать с **AEM** **(Adobe Experience Manager - он же CQ)**

Нужно выполнить логирование всех обращений к определенной ноде в **JCR** (запись/чтение).

как это можно реализовать?

где можно почитать?

примеры приветствуются

Answer (score 0):

Для этого вам нужно использовать JCR level listeners отлавливайте ивенты и логируйте что вам нужно.

1) Пример создания: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/aem64_event_listener.html
2) Здесь можно найти все типы ивентов: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jcr/2.0/12_Observation.html

Comment: спасибо за ответ.  Я пробовал использовать Observation... но это мне не совсем подходит... тк нужно отслеживать также и доступ на чтение.  а Observation не предоставляет такого типа события